# Set id for text inside link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a dropdown list having links to specific categories, in each line of category I want it to include name of category and number of books of that category. Anyway, I want the number part having a different style in comparison with name part.

Here is the code for each one:

```
%li= link_to "#{category.name} (#{category.books.count})" , root_path(category_id: category.id)
```

I want to set id for `#{category.name}` and `(#{category.books.count})`, what should I do?

Comment: You want `catagory_id` in root_path?

Comment: @Tan Nguyen Did I answered correctly your question? I answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the attribute `id`. In your code, you should do it like:

```
%li= link_to "#{category.name} (#{category.books.count})" , root_path(category_id: category.id), id: "#{category.name} (#{category.books.count})"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, we should use link_to do like this:

```
 = link_to root_path(category_id: category.id, per_page: params[:per_page]) do
          .row.cate-display
            #cate-name= category.name
            #cate-count= "(#{category.books.count})"
```